# PHP+Oauth/ different oauth providers return different user data. what to do?

Tags: php, oauth

I'm having login through several oauth providers on my site. The problem is that they all [oauth providers] return users data in different formats, e.g. `country=280` and `country=US` or `sex=male` and `sex=2`. Besides one field can have different name on different oauth providers, e.g. `sex` and `gender`.

Is there a *simple* way to bring it all to one system on names and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an abstraction layer to handle the specificities of each provider and bring them all to a common standard.

Writing a few configurations and a few lines of code to wrap it all qualifies as simple to me.

Comment: Well,the question was whether these all specifications are already gathered somewhere. Anyway, thank you!